# Z490 AORUS MASTER and Seagate BarraCuda PCIe 4

Tags: motherboard, compatibility, m.2

I have a Z490 AORUS MASTER and I already use a Seagate BarraCuda Q5 which is PCIe 3.

This motherboard has a builtin heatsink under which you mount the M.2 NVMes. The BarraCuda Q5 fits perfectly.

I want to by a second NVMe and I was looking at the Seagate BarraCuda PCIe 4. In the technical specs I noted that this one is 3.58 mm in height. The Q5 is only 2.15 mm, and it fits just right.

**The question: Will this PCIe 4 M.2 NVMe fit on the motherboard under the heatsink?**

Why the PCIe 4 version on this motherboard? Well, when I'll upgrade my motherboard I plan keeping this one, so I'd prever a PCIe 4 even though I know it will run at PCIe 3 speeds at the moment.